# Is there a way to toggle between html tags with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, tags, toggle

I can easily toggle between classes using `element.classList.toggle()`. Thus, using bootstrap 4, for example, it's easy to change a class, and no extra css is necessary.

I was wondering if there is an equivalent method for toggling between different tags.

A use case would be toggle between "bootstrap 4" inline text tags https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/typography/#inline-text-elements

Text decoration here is added by tags, and not by classes.

I did some previous research, and I've found other queries about toggle between divs. I also can figure out how to do it by creating a conditional statement.

But is there a way to toggle tags as easy as `element.classList.toggle()` using only javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Swap from `p` to `span` and preserving attributes.

```js
function swapTag(element, newTag) {
  // New element with the desired tag
  let newElement = document.createElement(newTag);
  
  // Copy of all attributes
  for(let attr of element.attributes) {
    newElement.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value);
  }
  
  // Replace
  element.replaceWith(newElement);
}

// Create two elements
var parent = document.createElement("div");
var child = document.createElement("p");
// Assign some style
child.style.color = "red";

parent.appendChild(child);

// Before
console.log(parent.outerHTML);

// Do the magic
swapTag(child, "span");

// After
console.log(parent.outerHTML);
```

Comment: Thank you Balastrong. It is deffinitily another way for doing it. Altough It is not as simple as ``element.classList.toggle()``.

Comment: The usage is as simple as `swapTag(element, "p")` though :)